# opening hallo editor on document ready

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, hallo-js

I'm trying to open the hallo editor toolbar on `document.ready` with `focus` on the first element or anywhere, it doesn't really matter I just need to open it

I tried triggering a click event on the editable element, and a focus event, nothing worked.
I have also tried to put the caret in the editable element:

```
var el = document.getElementById("content");
var range = document.createRange();
var sel = window.getSelection();
range.setStart(el.firstChild, 2);
range.collapse(true);
sel.removeAllRanges();
sel.addRange(range);
```

any other ideas?

Comment: If you want it on document ready you shoudl have the code on body Onload and not on `click event` or `focus event`

Comment: it's not on click, I have just initialized the editor, he binds on click on its own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, must insert the caret in the element and then trigger the event `halloactivated` on `document.ready`

```
   var range = rangy.createRange();
   var sel = rangy.getSelection();
   range.selectNode(el);
   sel.removeAllRanges();
   sel.addRange(range);

   jQuery('#content').trigger('halloactivated');
```